# Changing the number of outputs in a GET PHP function

Tags: php, html

Sorry if my title is a little vague? I am not too sure how to word it. I have created a website that generates text however right now

```
<?php

function randomGenerator($string)
{
    $string_array = str_split( $string );

    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    foreach ($string_array as $k => $v) {
        if ($v == '*')
            $string_array[$k] = rand(0,9);
        if ($v == '^')
            $string_array[$k] = $characters[rand(0,25)];
    }

    $string = implode('', $string_array);


    return $string;
}

echo randomGenerator($_GET["algo"]);
?>
```

and the algo is defined by an input box on another page. On that same page a user can also select a number of results to generate however I am having a hard time thinking of how to implement it into the PHP side of it. This is what I have on the other page.

```
<form action="AGR.php" method="get">
        <p><strong>The algorithm</strong></p>
        <input type="text" name="algo" width="10" style="margin : 0 auto; display: block;"><br>
        <p><strong>Number to produce </strong></p>
        Please select:  <select name="number" style="float:right;">
                        <option value="25">1</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                        </select><br>
        <p><div id="center"><input type="submit"></div></p>
    </form>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm pretty beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: `for($i = 1; $i <= $_GET['number']; $i++){ echo randomGenerator($_GET["algo"]); }`

Comment: if 25 selected you need 25 different randim generated string. is that right?

Comment: @syedmohamed that is correct :) I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: @Daan I tried that however as there is no line breaks it is all on one line. Should I add the line break after the echo bit?

Comment: Yes @Max you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if 25 selected you need 25 different randim generated string. is that right? if so, then try this

```
$number = $_GET['number'];
$algorithm = $_GET['algo'];
for($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++){ 
  echo $i.".".randomGenerator($algorithm)."<br/>"; //1.sjhgdhd 
                                                   //2.jkshagd
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much:) When I can I will select this as the answer.

Comment: @Max your'e welcome.you can accept it by clicking on the tick.